# Visual Studio как скопировать сообщение об ошибке?

Tags: visual-studio

Как скопировать сообщение об ошибке в Visual Studio (которое по наведению мыши)?

Answer (score 1):

Построить решение (F6) и там уже можно будет скопировать.